# Python で 二次元配列を print すると結果が省略されるが、全て表示させたい

Tags: python

割と量のある二次元配列に対して

```
print data
```

とした時に下記のように省略されるのですが、ファイルに書き出したいので全部出して欲しい時はどうすればよいですか？

```
[[a,b,c ..., x,y,z]
[a,b,c ..., x,y,z]
....,
[a,b,c ..., x,y,z]
[a,b,c ..., x,y,z]]
```

Comment: dataは普通のpythonのリストですか？何らかのライブラリなどの「リストの様な」オブジェクトですか？

Comment: 本当にただ「みたい」だけなのか、それともデータを保存しておいてあとで Python から再利用するのかで回答が違ってきます。目的を明確にするとよりよい回答が得られ、また他の人にも有益になります。

Comment: 目で見た後でdatにしたいと思っていたので下記の回答でOKでした

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print <python-object>` としたときにPythonのリストオブジェクトや辞書オブジェクトのプログラムコードのように出力されているのは、「たまたま」です。人間が見やすいように整形しているので、長い場合は途中で省略されます。

データを完全な状態でファイルに保存する、つまりシリアライズする方法はいくつかあります。このとき、どのようなフォーマットでファイルに書き出したいかによって実装方法は異なります。単に、人間が見るだけれあれば（再利用しないのであれば）、シリアライズをちゃんと考えるよりも楽に解決できそうです。

人間が見やすければOKな出力（画面の横幅はきっと広い）:

```
lines = []
for r in data:
    lines.append(', '.join(r))
print '\n'.join(lines)
```

print風味でprintを使って出力(Pythonのリストの文法と一致させる):

```
lines = []
for r in data:
    lines.append('[' + ', '.join(r) + ']')
print '[' + ',\n'.join(lines) + ']'
```

csvで出力(一般的に再利用しやすい方法):

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'wt') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)

# csv.reader を使えば読み込みが出来ます
```

pickleで出力(Pythonで再利用しやすい方法):

```
import pickle
# write
with open('file.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

# read
with open('file.p', 'rb') as f:
    d2 = pickle.load(f)
```

Answer (score 6):

これはnumpyですか？だとしたら

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
```

と先頭でやれば全部表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

pandasなら

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 最大表示列数)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 最大表示行数)
```

なのでこの最大値を10000000くらいにしたら、表示が可能です